# dojo combobox max. characters

Tags: combobox, dojo, character, max

I created a ComboBox using dojo like below. How to set the max. number of characters allowed in the ComboBox so when max. reached user can't type any more?

```js
var comboBox = new ComboBox({
     id: "Person",
     name: "Person",
     store: personStore,
     constraints: { maxlength: 40 },
     searchAttr: "name"
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add the constraint on root.

```
    var comboBox1 = new ComboBox({
    store: restStore,
    searchAttr: "Name",
    autocomplete: true,
    placeholder: "Select your favorite song.",
    maxlength:'5'
}, "comboBox1Placeholder");
```